# Python readlines() doesn't function outputs bug in for loop

Tags: python, python-3.x

**Intro:**
I'm a beginner python learning syntax at the moment. I've come across this concept of reading and writing files natively supported by python. I've figured to give it a try and find bugs after attempting looping reading and writing commands. I wanted to randomly pick a name from a name file and then writing it into a new file. My file includes 19239 lines of names, randrange(18238) generates from 0 - 18238, and, supposedly, would read a randomly read a line between 1 - 18239. **The problem is that the code that reads and writes works without the for loop but not with the for loop.**

**My attempt:**

```
from random import randrange
rdname = open("names.dat", "r")
wrmain = open("main.dat", "a")
rdmain = open("main.dat", "r")

for x in range(6):
    nm = rdname.readlines()[randrange(18238)]
    print(str(randrange(18238)) + ": " + nm)
    wrmain.write("\n" + nm)
...
```

**Error code:**

```
Exception has occurred: IndexError
list index out of range
```

Comment: Please supply the expected [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).  Show where the intermediate results differ from what you expected.
We should be able to copy and paste a contiguous block of your code, execute that file, and reproduce your problem along with tracing output for the problem points.  This lets us test our suggestions against your test data and desired output.

Comment: In particular, we expect you to perform the straightforward debugging before you post here.  How many iterations did the loop run before the error?  How many lines were in the file?  What is the value of the index?  Given this information, what don't you understand about the problem?

Comment: I wouldn't recommend opening the same file two times in two different modes, but you aren't using `rdmain` anyway.

Comment: Have you done *any* debugging at all? The issue should become obvious with minimal effort

Comment: Just use readlines() once and then use the list it returned each time in the for loop

Comment: Maybe you need to rewind the file (seek or similar) in order to read again 18k lines?

Comment: You could debug this incredibly easily yourself if (for example) you just assigned the result of readlines to a variable like `lines` and then printed the length of `lines`

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion @Prune. I'm sorry for the bothersome. I'm really new to the platform and thought it would be okay to ask a quick question that I really didn't know where the problem happened. I'm not particularly familar with the concept of debugging juanpa.arrivillaga.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`rdname.readlines()` exhausts your file handle. Running `rdname.readlines()` gives you the list of lines the first time, but returns an empty list every subsequent time. Obviously, you can't access an element in an empty list. To fix this, assign the result of `readlines()` to a variable just once, before your loop.

```
rdlines = rdname.readlines()
maxval = len(rdlines)
for x in range(6):
    randval = randrange(maxval)
    nm = rdlines[randval]
    print(str(randval) + ": " + nm)
    wrmain.write("\n" + nm)
```

Also, making sure your random number can only go to the length of your list is a good idea. No need to hardcode the length of the list though -- the `len()` function will give you that.

I highly recommend you take a look at [how to debug small programs.](//ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) Using a debugger to step through your code is immensely helpful because you can see how each line affects the values of your variables. In this case, if you'd looked at the value of `nm` in each iteration, it would be obvious why you got the `IndexError`, and finding out that `nm` becomes an empty list on `readlines()` would point you in the direction of the answer.

Comment: Thank you for you reccomendation to the "how to debug small programs". I'm really new, and not familar with how to debug at all.

Answer (score 2):

Good luck with your programming journey.

The `readlines()` method. Has some non-intuitive behaviour. When you use the `readlines()` it "dumps" the entire content of the file and returns a list of strings of each line. Thus the second time you call the `rdname.readlines()[randrange(18238)]`, the `rdname` file object is completely empty and you actually have an empty list. So functionally you are telling your programme to run `[][randrange(18238)]` on the second iteration of the loop.

I also took the liberty of fixing the random number call, as the way you had implemented it would mean it would call 2 different random numbers when selecting the name `nm = rdname.readlines()[randrange(18238)]` and printing the selected name and linenumber `print(str(randrange(18238)) + ": " + nm)`

```
...
rdname = open("names.dat", "r")
wrmain = open("main.dat", "a")
rdmain = open("main.dat", "r")

rdname_list = rdname.readlines()

for x in range(6):
    rd_number = randrange(18238)
    nm = rdname_list[rd_number]
    print(str(rd_number) + ": " + nm)
    wrmain.write("\n" + nm)
...
```

Comment: Thank you very much, as well as for the second part.